# How to create new URL views in asp .net MVC at run time(as like Stackoverflow)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, view, runtime

In my new project i need to create **new static `url Views`** with user content at `run time` in asp.net MVC.

For that i have taken [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as an example.

In SO when we ask the question we will type our question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and finally we go for "Post your question" button.

Once we post the question one new static URL will be generated with our contents(i'm not sure they may handle it through some url routing mechanism).

***And my question is:***

**How should i create new static URL views(with contents) in runtime using asp .net MVC?**

Note: I considered about `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl` but im not sure is this correct approach and i'm little bit concerned if we keep on add views into our solution the size of solution will be so much bigger at some point of time.Is there any better approach to over come this issue?

Comment: StackOverflow is not creating new static anything at runtime. There's simply a route, `/questions/{id}/{slug}`, and when a request is made for a URL matching that route, it's directed to something that will then use the `id` and/or `slug` parameters obtained from the URL to attempt to find a question in the database. If no match is found, a 404 is returned, otherwise, they use this question object to dynamically render a view that is returned as the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic routing and querying content based on ID:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "questionsFull",
            url: "questions/{questionId}/{questionTitleForSeo}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Questions", action = "Full"});
```

And in your controller read article by `questionId`

```
class QuestionController 
{....
    ActonResult(string questionId) { return ArticleById(questionId);}
```

To create urls in the Razor view (assuming you have `question` variable - i.e. if you pass list of "Question" objects as model):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Full", "Question", new {question.Id})>
       @question.Title</a>
```